# Unexpected null behavior with HttpResponseMessage.Content in .NET core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm writing a piece of code which is basically an API client inside a **.NET core 3.1 class library**.
I'm using **Visual Studio 2019 enterprise version 16.5.5**.

I have enabled the nullable reference type feature, in order to enjoy the compiler warnings for nulls in Visual Studio. This is the csproj of my class library project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Flurl" Version="2.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="3.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="4.7.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In my code I want to ensure that the response content type is actually `application/json`, which is the expected reuturn type from my API:

```
var responseMediaType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
```

By checking the type annotations of the involved objects and the visual studio intellisense I can read that none of the objects I'm dereferencing is expected to be `null` (the visual studio intellisense says that 'Content is not null here', 'Headers is not null here' and so on...).

A simple check to the [.NET core github repository seems to confirm that calling the getter for property `Content` of class `HttpResponseMessage` never returns `null`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8b24e646a7ee754213a94b757e55995326fdf722/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs#L46). By checking the code, it seems that setting a `null` value to the property is allowed, but when the getter is invoked the underlying field is changed to `new EmptyContent()` by means of the `??=` operator.

So, based on my understanding, **the getter for this property never returns null**, according to the property type (which is the *non nullable reference type* `HttpContent`) and the visual studio intellisense. So far, so good.

Some times ago I wrote a similar piece of code and we had a subtle bug with one of our customers. Due to a very long request query string the called endpoint returned a `414 URI too long` response having **no response content**. In that case, dereferencing the `Content` property in order to detect the response mime type caused a `NullReferenceException`. This happened with a **.NET core 2.2 class library**.

In order to avoid making the same mistake twice, I have added a unit test for my brand new .NET core 3.1 code where I use a mock for the called API, configured this way (in order to reproduce the same scenario that bit me previously):

```
_messageHandlerMock
        .Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
          "SendAsync",
          ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
          ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
        )
        .Returns(async () =>
        {
          await Task.Delay(2).ConfigureAwait(false);

          return new HttpResponseMessage
          {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RequestUriTooLong,
            Content = null
          };
        });
```

The test fails with a `NullReferenceException` raised when `response.Content.Headers` is dereferenced, because the value of `response.Content` is `null`.

This is **unexpected** to me, due to the visual studio intellisense suggestions, the non nullable reference type of `Content` property and the source code of the `HttpResponseMessage` class linked above.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you sure your mock (and the callback in ReturnsAsync) is being used? I seem to remember a very similar problem I had several months ago when trying to mock that same protected method where it just wasn't getting invoked. Can't recall what the problem ended up being or how I got around it.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I'm sure the mock is actually used. If you need some code samples to mock an HTTP client follow this guide https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/. I found it useful, we always use this approach for these kind of unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're looking at was only commited 8 days ago. Here is the version you're likely using:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4b03513e20e0caf9ee34817eb74356903f1bb33e/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs#L44

As you can see it returns content without a null check.

There was an updated pushed out 3 days ago which may now use this code I'm unsure however. I would recommend updating or else changing your code to not set content to null.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was fooled by the visual studio intellisense suggestion about the nullability. For some strange reason, it seems to use the type annotations for the latest version of the code.